# display data in textarea

Tags: php, html, mysql

hello i have a table that has column send and column answer, like this :
http://gyazo.com/3ab5445f8bab390834b9c0dfc2e5219f

what i want to do is to display them in textarea like this :
gyazo.com/c4d3b561577cb6476fd2cf0e792e30ec

this  is my code

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';

$name=$user_data['first_name'];
$name=htmlentities(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($name)));



$query= mysql_query("SELECT    `send`, `answer` FROM messages WHERE user ='$name'");
$finalRes = array();
if(!$query) {
    var_export(mysql_error());
}
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
   $finalRes[] = $result;
}
if (!empty($finalRes)){


 foreach ($finalRes as $URL){
echo  "<font color='green'>you </font>".$URL['send']."";
echo "<br>";

echo "<font color='red'>admin </font> ".$URL['answer']."";
echo "<br>";
}

}
?>
<textarea  > </textarea>
```

and this is the result i get from it :

gyazo.com/72506891250fa9df6ff328316416fc5d

thanks for the help !!

Comment: just enclose the result in a text area tag

Comment: and use `&#13;&#10;` for the new line instead of the `<br/>` tag

Comment: how? this didnt work if (!empty($finalRes)){
echo'<textarea>';

 foreach ($finalRes as $URL){
echo  "<font color='green'>you </font>".$URL['send']."";
echo "<br>";

echo "<font color='red'>admin </font> ".$URL['answer']."";
echo "<br>";
}

echo'</textarea>';
}

Comment: it will work if you **(1)** remove the `font` tag, just put plain text like `echo 'you: ' . $URL['send']` **(2)** use `echo '&#13;&#10;'` instead of `echo '<br/>'`

Comment: thanks that worked,but how am i suposed to color "you" green and "admin" red now?

Comment: you can't do that in a normal HTML text area (the only thing that you can do is coloring the entire text through css)

Comment: ok thanks so much for the help brother,i will juse use fieldset instead it works better